# Blogdown - submit/receive an email to access/download a file in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, hugo, blogdown

I have a personal webpage (which I built using Blogdown in Rstudio and host it in GitHub) with a downloadable file. In order to,  once to download the file,  1) I want to create a pop-up to ask the users to provide a valid email address, then after the email address is confirmed, they can download the .pdf from my personal webpage. 2) I would like to also receive an email about who download the .pdf file (using which email address).

any help would be appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a great question. I was thinking you would have to use Shiny, but then it's a personal website and not just an Rmarkdown file with runtime shiny.

Comment: It is just a  Rmarkdown webpage.